# WMS getcapabilities get the xml only for specific layer

Tags: wms

I need to check the dimension 'time' of a specific layer to see if there is a new image available. For that I need to grab the complete XML again using the getcapabilities request. Some XML's are so huge that it takes seconds to parse them......

How can I retrieve only the XML-part for a specific layer?